# I need to learn about org.hibernate.HibernateException

Tags: hibernate

**NOTE: Update#1 and Update#2 has UserDAOImpl.java, HibernateConfig.java, UserServiceImpl.java**

**Get closer**

As I know that you need to being transaction from Hibernate SessionFactory.
Running queries after getting session using getCurrentSession() won't work until you being transaction.
So using @Transactional on your @Repository or @Service would let spring apply transaction for queries of its method.

Why entityManager didn't need transaction, I will dig into

---

I need to know what to read to understand what this exception means:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
```

I know that some answers suggests @EnableTransactionManagement, and some answers @Transactional, I will copy/paste solutions for now.

I am a very basic user, I don't know much about RDBMS, I know basics of how to deal with MySQL, so If you could just list a number of topics to read that would be enough.

**Update#1**

I have two queries that one work and the other gives me this exception and I don't have @Transactional on any of my Service classes:

**UserDAOImpl.java**

```
@Component
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    // Works well
    @Override
    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        return (User) sessionFactory.createEntityManager()
                        .createQuery("from User where username = :username")
                        .setParameter("username", username)
                        .getSingleResult(); 
    }

    // Gives me the exception
    @Override
    public User findByUsernameOneColumn(String username, String column) {
        return (User) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                        .createQuery("select :column from User where username = :username")
                        .setParameter("column", column)
                        .setParameter("username", username)
                        .getSingleResult();
    }


}
```

That is why I needed to read more rather than copy paste, I should not be given -1, I need to learn well.

**Update#2**

**HibernateConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/medicallabDB");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        try {
            localSessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
            localSessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
            localSessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("medicallab.web.model");


            localSessionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();           

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return localSessionFactory;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");

        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        return userDAO.findByUsername(username);
    }

    @Override
    public User findByUsernameOneColumn(String username, String column) {
        User user = null;

        try {
            user = userDAO.findByUsernameOneColumn(username, column);
            System.out.println("user object" + user);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return user;
    }

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No such user: " + username);
        }

        return new User(user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must enable the transaction support ( or @EnableTransactionManagement) and declare the transactionManager and it should work through the SessionFactory.

You must add @Transactional into your @Repository

With @Transactional in your @Repository Spring is able to apply transactional support into your repository.

Comment: Please upload your full code. And explain your question correctly

Comment: Okay @Shanmugapriya, that is why the question about learning, so that I don't apply different copy/paste until I pass the problem, I am preparing it.

Comment: Refer the following url. You may get some idea about that error  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/TransactionException.html

Comment: But do you want to say that createEntityManager do the beginTransaction, I think I need to lean the difference between entity manager and session

Comment: UserDAOImpl.java, HibernateConfig.java, UserServiceImpl.java has been added.